# JavaScript Websocket Own Close Code

Tags: javascript, angularjs, websocket

I have run in to the following problem:
For a customer I have to be able to open websocket connection to different websockets, depending on the current view.
The Connection & Message Handling is no issue & is all working as intended.
However, I wanted to implement a function that closes the open websockets when switching views, so they don't stay running for no reason.
I do this through the following code :

```
$scope.closeOpenWebsockets = function () {    
    var  socketLength  =  $scope.openWebsockets.length;    
    while (socketLength--) {      
        console.log($scope.openWebsockets[socketLength]);
         $scope.openWebsockets[socketLength].close(4999);    
    }    
     $scope.openWebsockets  =   [];
};

$scope.addOpenWebsocket = function (socket) {    
     $scope.openWebsockets.push(socket);
};
```

This does work, the only thing I can't get working is changing the close code of the websocket.
Based on the list I found here : 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CloseEvent

I tried using various codes listed there, but none seem to work. everytime I call the .close() myself, the close code I get back is 1006. Above example is with 4999, a close code normally available for applications. But also did not work when trying to send for example 1000.

The reason I need this is because the connection can also be closed from the other side, & in this case I need to try and reconnect. (It's always a close event & not an error event).

I hoped to do this based on close code, but I wanted to choose the code I sent when closing manually so that I am sure I'm not blocking any other close codes I might receive (I can only do limited tests with the source system & thus I am  not 100% sure of all possible codes I might receive)

As probably visible in the code, I'm doing this in AngularJS.

Am I missing something here? I have looked through numerous stackoverflow posts/websocket guides and so on. But I haven't found anything.

Edit : This was one of the guides I found: 
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/websockets/websockets_closing_connection.htm